# Find multiple tangents for parabola

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have a parabola $x = 0.5y^2 - 4y + 3$. I need to find a tangent(s) that go throught point $(2,-1)$. I have tried:

$y - (-1) = m(x-2)$

$4y = 0.5y^2 - x + 3$

$y = (0.5y^2)/4 - x/4 + 3/4$

$m(x-2) - 1 = (0.5y^2)/4 - x/4 + 3/4$

But I'm pretty sure that's incorrect, could I have some advise on the problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: Can I have some help guys? I'm stuck...

Comment: $$s_{11}^2=s\cdot s_1$$

$$(\frac12 (x+2) -( \frac12 y \cdot (-1) - 2(y-1) + 3))^2=(x - (\frac12 y^2 - 4y + 3))(2 -( \frac12 (-1)^2 - 4(-1) + 3))$$

$$(x-2)^2 + 10 (x-2) (y+1) + 14 (y+1)^2 = 0$$

$$x-2+(5\pm \sqrt{11})(y+1)=0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation of parabola is $x = 0.5y^2 - 4y + 3$. You can write tangent points to the parabola as $(0.5t^2 - 4t + 3, t)$.

Slope at the tangent point $ = \displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{t-4}$

So the tangent lines are given by,

$\displaystyle y-t = \frac{1}{t-4} (x - 0.5t^2 + 4t - 3) $

As the tangents go through point $(2, -1)$

$\displaystyle -1-t = \frac{1}{t-4} (2 - 0.5t^2 + 4t - 3) $

Solving, $t = -1 \pm \sqrt{11}$

So equation of tangent lines can be written as,

$ \displaystyle y + 1 = \frac{1}{-5 \pm \sqrt{11}} (x - 2)$

Comment: This makes sense. Big thanks to both you and @PierreCarre for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see where these equations come from?

$$
\begin{cases} 
x= 2 + m(y+1) &\qquad&(1)\\
m = -4+y &&(2)\\
x = \frac 12 y^2 -4y +3 &&(3)\\
\end{cases}
$$

The tangency point belongs to both the parabola and the tangent line (equations 1 and 3), and the slope of the tangent line is the derivative at the tangency point (equation 2).

This way you find two solutions, for $y=-1\pm\sqrt{11}$, with slopes $-5 \pm \sqrt{11}$.

[image]

Comment: Last one is the equation of parabola, other two come from example that I tried to follow but I wasn't successful.

Comment: The point of tangency belongs to both the parabola and the tangent line (eqs 1 and 3). The slope of the tangent line corresponds to the derivative at the tangency point (eq. 2). From those equations you get the coordinates of the tangency point and the slope.

Comment: Can you show an example? I'm new to the world of analytical geometry.

Comment: That is a graphical solution (also very useful), but could you show an algebraic one?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer This is not a graphical solution... I got the graphic from the solution of the system, not the other way round. If you substitute $x= \frac 12 y^2-4y+3$ and $m = -4+y$ in the first equation, you get a second degree equation in $y$ only. You solve it, getting $y = -1 \pm\sqrt{11}$ and substitute back in the other equations to the $x$ and $m$.

Comment: Ah I see, that's more clear... I will practice more with similar parabolas.